# Recover Facebook account, without access to email and

Tags: facebook, account-recovery, facebook-privacy, mobile, facebook-account

We have the following scenario:

- Alice is authenticated on Facebook on her phone.
- She forgot the password of her Facebook account
- Can't access the email associated with the Facebook account and does not have other emails. Can't recover the email account either.
- She does have the phone number connected with her Facebook account, but
- When she uses the *Forgotten Password* feature, she doesn't have the option to reset the password via SMS.
- The Facebook account is already connected with her actual phone number.

What are the steps for Alice to be able to use Facebook on her computer? How can she reset the password in this situation?

Comment: _"She does have the phone number connected with her Facebook account, but ...she doesn't have the option to reset the password via SMS."_ Why? If we know why we could find an alternative solution.

Comment: @marikamitsos I don't know why... I expected Facebook would show the option to send the SMS, but that does not happen.

Comment: _"I expected Facebook would show the option to send the SMS"_ Did it ever and is somehow now removed?

Comment: Can she log-in her account through her phone?

Comment: @marikamitsos She is already logged in through her phone for a long time, but in the meantime she forgot the password. I don't think the SMS option was removed, but it is definitely not showing up for her.

Comment: Has she tried the [identify your account](https://facebook.com/login/identify) link?

Comment: @marikamitsos Yes, I sent her that link and she has only the email option. Then she clicked the option that she can't access the email. And eventually the message was lik _We can't identify you, we are sorry_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app settings, the phone number was already added, but not in the right place.

By adding the phone number in the identification section, **specifically, where the email was specified already**, added the phone successfully.

Once the phone number was confirmed, the reset password worked via SMS.